# Dates and timezones in Hive

Tags: date, hive, timezone

I am struggling to understand how Hive deals with dates and timezones:

```
select item_id, cal_dt from ds where item_id = 7208582515 and cal_dt='2019-02-11';
7208582515      2019-02-10
```

I know it has to be a timezone issue. It's 11 pm PDT right now (same as the Hadoop cluster time, I think) but Hive (1.2) is running on a node without any timezone (UTC).

Previously, I had a bigger issue where a query with this condition:

```
next_dt = date_add(cal_dt,1)
```

It didn't work on the clock change dates. I think that was because my TZ was set to America/Los_Angeles so I unset it.

I don't know what's going on. I didn't expect dates to be affected by the timezone. What's the right thing to do?

Comment: Just ask Hive what time zone it uses internally: `select current_timestamp() as DEF_FMT_IN_DEF_TZ, to_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp()) as DEF_FMT_IN_UTC, date_format(current_timestamp()),'XXX') as DEF_TZ_ISO`

Comment: Hive reference for date functions https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions  Java reference for SimpleDateFormat https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Recommended reading : _"Falsehoods programmers believe about time"_ (and it's not even a complete list) https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time

Comment: Bottom line: you may have to +/- a number of hours (or hafl-hours if you are dealing witn India) from you "user" TZ to match the "Hive" TZ. That number may change twice a year thanks to DST. You may code the rule in a "temporary macro" so that the conversion is inlined automatically in your queries. Enjoy your next days of development and testing...

Comment: Something must be wrong with the Hive installation on the node. It's 10 am now and I am still getting 2019-02-10 so it can't be the timezone. Plus, spark-sql returns the right result. Setting TZ to PDT seems to fix the Hive issue. Very strange. Maybe Hive can't handle a NULL timezone

Comment: Spark has its own rules for setting the TZ - and mot always in a consistent way, i.e. if executors run on hosts with different default TZ and you did not force the TZ globally with a Spark property _(which was added fairly recently BTW)_ then you are in trouble...

Comment: _"so it can't be the TZ"_ >> did you check the TZ, or not?? if not, then just ask Nostradamus for advice. StackOverflow deals with facts, not opinions, faith, superstitions etc.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I don't know how to interpret the results:
`hive> select current_timestamp() as DEF_FMT_IN_DEF_TZ, to_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), 'PDT') as DEF_FMT_IN_UTC, date_format(current_timestamp(),'XXX') as DEF_TZ_ISO;
OK
2019-09-08 21:44:07.549 2019-09-08 21:44:07.549 Z `
It's 14:44 PDT right now.

Comment: `Z` means "zero offset from UTC" i.e. UTC i.e Universal Time _(formerly GMT for Greewich Meridian)_  -- and indeed what Hive displays for "local time" is the same as for "UTC time". For the record, right now it's 10:28 CEST => 8:28 UTC => 1:28 PDT